# Trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 i386 as a VM in VirtualBox, the system crashes upon completion

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox, windows-8, virtualization, restart

I followed numerous tutorials to download Ubuntu 13.04, and it continues to crash at the end of the setup. I basically followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcUYRWy8L74). I am prompted to restart my computer at the end of the setup, and then it crashes. I also clicked *Force Unmount* at the bottom right-hand corner, and nothing happened.

I have Windows 8, an Intel i7 in my Samsung Series 5 laptop. Also, I used a fixed size HD of 16GB instead of dynamic. Also, I tried to encrypt. I also tried installing Ubuntu 12.04, and a bunch of other things. Can someone tell me what to do at the end of the setup so this thing doesn't crash?

Comment: I also tried this twice last night - I've decided to try 12.04 tonight. I chose to have an expandable virtual hard drive in my VirtualBox settings - I also chose to wipe the current non-existing operating system but did not chose the options on that same page on the install. There was an option for creating a smarter partition or something - will try that too.

Comment: This time while installing I chose the LVM option during install and it worked ok.

Comment: Now I addded guest additions and it will not restart. Back to my 10.04 attempt

Answer (score 0):

- Use VirtualBox 4.2.14 or later.
- Do not encrypt your hard drive- I've noticed undefined results.
- Make sure you have at least 512MB RAM 1GB would be better for 13.04.
- Use as much video memory as you can. 128MB seems to be best.
- Enable 3D in the video.

After install, you may have to Power Off machine through VirtualBox.
After install it will run slow so use `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` from the command line to get updates.

Then, install Guest Additions. This may be slow and hinky due to poor graphic response. 
When you restart it should work.
Finally, use `sudo apt-get install dkms` to keep VirtualBox kernel drivers in sync with any kernel updates.